Golden ratio inequality - Possible to prove?
I was trying to prove this integral was less than $1/2$:
$$  I=\int_0^{1/\phi} e^{\frac{\log^2 \phi}{\log x}}~dx<\frac{1}{2} \tag{prove}$$
I decomposed$^{***}$ the integral into two parts and multiplied through by $2$:
$$\frac{1}{\phi^2}+\int_0^1 e^{\frac{\log^2 \phi}{\log x}}~dx <1$$
The integral simplifies to a Bessel function $K_1$ and we get the following:
$$ \frac{1}{\phi^2}+ 2\log (\phi) K_1(2\log(\phi)) <1 $$
Referencing the relationship:
$$\frac{1}{\phi^2}+\frac{1}{\phi}=1$$
We now have to show that:
$$ 2\log (\phi) K_1(2\log(\phi))<\frac{1}{\phi}. $$
I can't proceed from here without using numerical methods, which say the RHS is $.618$ and the LHS is $.617$.

Is it possible to get bounds that will allow me to prove the inequality? Are only numerics possible to obtain the result?

$^{***}$The decomposition of the integral is obtained in the following manner:
We use the following lemma: The integrand $J(x)$ is involutive in the sense that $J(J(x))=x.$
This implies that the line $y=x$ equally divides the area for:
$$ L=\int_0^1 J(x)dx $$
such that $L/2$ is one of these halves. However we have to add a triangular area that is left over:
We make a triangle with three points: $a=(1/\phi,1/\phi)$ and $b=(0,0,0)$ and $c=(1/\phi,0)$ and the area of said Euclidean triangle is:
$$ \frac{bh}{2}=\frac{1}{2\phi^2} $$
where $b$ is the base and $h$ is the height.
We know have the following decomposition of I:
$$ I=L/2+\frac{1}{2\phi^2}$$
which is in direct agreement with the below answers.

How did you change the endpoint of integration? Where did the $1/\phi^2$ come from?

Do not forget that we know the infinite series giving $t$ solution of $g(t)=0$.

@GregMartin I bisected the integrand with the identity function. Due to the involutive property of the integrand, this bisection decomposes the integral into a triangular portion and a bessel portion. I hope that makes sense.

I, at least, still don't understand those steps. Perhaps adding information to the OP will help other readers as well.

I will make the effort to include those steps. I also think it will help other readers

@GregMartin I added my steps. Thanks for the suggestion

Consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=2x\,\log (x)\, K_1(2\log(x))-1$$ Let $x=e^{t/2}$ and then
$$g(t)=t\,e^{t/2}\, K_1(t)-1$$ Now expand
$$t\,e^{t/2}\, K_1(t)=\sqrt{e}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,(t-1)^n$$ where the first coefficients
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & K_1(1) \\
 1 & \frac{5 K_1(1)}{2}-K_2(1) \\
 2 & \frac{21 K_1(1)}{8}-K_2(1) \\
 3 & \frac{73 K_1(1)}{48}-\frac{13 K_2(1)}{24} \\
 4 & \frac{83 K_1(1)}{128}-\frac{K_2(1)}{4} \\
 5 & \frac{829 K_1(1)}{3840}-\frac{29 K_2(1)}{384} \\
 6 & \frac{2669 K_1(1)}{46080}-\frac{137 K_2(1)}{5760} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ are alternating and smaller and smaller
$$\left|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|\sim 1-\frac{43}{15\,n}$$
Using the above terms and power series reversion, converted to decimals
$$t=\color{red}{0.96090560}82$$
Using the expansion to $O((t-1)^{13})$ would give
$$t=\color{red}{0.960905607171122}61\quad \implies \quad x=1.616806~<~\phi$$
Edit
In fact, it is not necessary to use many terms. Expanding $g(t)$ to $O((t-1)^{n+1})$, performing series reversion to get $t_{(n)}$ and the corresponding $x_{(n)}$, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_{(n)} \\
 1 & 1.61728217931 \\
 2 & 1.61683456507 \\
 3 & 1.61680813469 \\
 4 & 1.61680646177 \\
 5 & 1.61680634212 \\
 6 & 1.61680633297 \\
 7 & 1.61680633224 \\
 8 & 1.61680633218 \\
 9 & 1.61680633217 \\
 10 & 1.61680633217 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Update
Even if $t_{(1)}$ is fine, we know in advance (by Darboux theorem) that it is an overestimate of the solution since $g(1)$ and $g''(1)$ are both negative; so the convergence will be from above (as shown in the table).
Concerning the inverse series, using $$a=\sqrt{e}\, K_1(1)-1\qquad \text{and}\qquad b=5 K_1(1)-2 K_2(1)$$
$$t_{(2)}=1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{e}\, b}(g(t)-a)+\frac{8 K_2(1)-21 K_1(1)}{e\, b^3}(g(t)-a)^2$$
